What must be United with a set to get its subset? And intersection of which set with with another set yields in superset of that set?
Given that

A ⊂ μ
B ⊂ μ
A ⊂ B
(Where μ is universal set)

Find X and Y such that

B ∪ X = A
A ∩ Y = B

We know that for numbers we have Additive and Multiplicative Identities and Inverses, I was curious if operations that we do on set also has those Identities and Inverses or not.
I figured out that

Unitive Identity : Subset of that set.
Intersective Identity : Superset of that set

But what I couldn't find out was

Unitive Inverse
Intersective Inverse

So I framed this question in such a way that answer will yield those inverses. Although I am not that deep into field of mathematics I am just a high schooler who raise such questions out of curiosity. Please reply.

You can't, assuming the subset in $3.$ is strict (or at least may be).  If there is any element of $B$ that is not in $A$, taking the union of $B$ with anything cannot remove it for the first and taking the intersection of $A$ with anything cannot add it in.

Is it the nature of those operations like union is a counterpart of addition or it is inclusive in nature and intersection is exclusive in nature?If you know please answer

Union is inclusive and intersection is exclusive.
